# Two versions of Pandas causing problems

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, version, conda

It appears that when I run `>conda list`, I have two versions of `pandas` installed.

```
pandas                 0.23.4              py36h830ac7b_0
pandas                 0.22.0              <pip>
```

I cannot run `import pandas` or `import pandas as pd` in my console (Anaconda - Spyder/Jupyter Notebook) to check the version, but I am getting errors thrown in a script related to `pandas`:

> Traceback (most recent call last) ...
>   from pandas.errors import
>   AbstractMethodError
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'AbstractMethodError'

I was going to do `>conda update pandas` but it said that my `numpy` would be downgraded. That doesn't sound right! How do I fix this?

Comment: Looks like you're mixing `pip install` and `conda install`

Comment: Right. So I want to uninstall the pip version. Could I just do `>pip uninstall pandas`? Would that automatically uninstall just the pip'd version (0.22.0)?

Comment: Please also do not post terminal/code output in images. Please see here for why: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/40481

Comment: The image has been removed @darthbith

Comment: @gwydion93 Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be hard for someone on SO to debug your exact issue: The fastest way to fix your particular problem is most likely a fresh install of `Anaconda`. Then to set up a `conda` environment in your fresh install.

See the following:

- [Conda Environments: Creating an Environment](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands)
- [Powershell users will need this fix](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/626#issue-30400607)

This will avoid any conflicts with other python versions or `pip`

This will also allow you to maintain different environments with different versions of `numpy` or `pandas`

See below for an example of how simple this is to switch between `2.7` and `3.6`

```
[py27] PS C:\Users\me> python --version
Python 2.7.15 :: Anaconda, Inc.
[py27] PS C:\Users\me> deactivate

Deactivating environment "py27..."


PS C:\Users\me> activate deeplearning

Activating environment "deeplearning..."


[deeplearning] PS C:\Users\me> python --version
Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
```

Comment: It was a nightmare setting up my new Anaconda environment with Python 3.6 (I also have 2.7 installed and multiple GIS platforms), so I'd really like to avoid a complete reinstall of Anaconda3. Isn't there a way I can just uninstall the pip'd pandas?

Comment: I know your pain, I have helped a lot of people do this and my company and honestly it's a lot less effort if you do it this way... Each environment can specify a different `python` version - so you don't need multiply platforms. Now instead of having multiple anacondas you just need to do something like `activate py27`; `deactivate`; `activate py36` and you've just switched between `2.7` and `3.6` it's literally that easy

Comment: So, what you're saying is, I need to go to my program files, remove Anaconda completely, then reinstall it from here: https://www.anaconda.com/download/? My original installation came bundled with my ArcGIS Pro configured for Python 3.6, which is what I need. I have a separate 2.7 environment configured for ArcGIS Desktop. I use PyWin/PyScripter for that. In the past, in order to get the proper ArcGIS Pro environment that I needed, I would have to copy the env folder from ArcGIS Pro(arcgispro-py3), move it to the Anaconda3/envs folder and rename it. Does that sound correct? Suggestions?